# Get values of one column and pass it to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and if I click a button i want to take the value from charge_outstanding_NUM and set charge_receipt_NUM to it. I need a reusable script because I will not know how many rows will get posted through.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Outstanding</th>
      <th>Reciept</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>150.00</td>
      <td id="charge_outstanding_1">150.00</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="charge_receipt_1" id="charge_receipt_1" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>002</td>
      <td>10.00</td>
      <td id="charge_outstanding_2">10.00</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="charge_receipt_2" id="charge_receipt_2" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>003</td>
      <td>250.00</td>
      <td id="charge_outstanding_3">250.00</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="charge_receipt_3" id="charge_receipt_3" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My jquery isn't working and I am not sure why. I click the button then loop through each col that starts with 'charge_outstanding_' then take the value and assign it to the closest input which is within the same row.

```
$('#pay_in_full').click(function(){
    $("[id^=charge_outstanding_]").each(function(){
        charge = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest('input').val(charge);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5NvW/2/

Issue with your code: `charge = $(this).val();` you are finding `td` which has no value, you need `.html()` for this

```
$(document).on("click", "#pay_in_full", function() {
    $("[id^=charge_outstanding_]").each(function(){
        var charge = $(this).html();
        $(this).next().find('input').val(charge);
    });
});
```

Suggestion: use class name with each `<td>` like this

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5NvW/

Note: less error prone..

```
$(document).on("click", "#pay_in_full", function() {
    $(".outstanding").each(function(){
        var charge = $(this).html();
        $(this).next().find('.paidAmount').val(charge);
    });
});
```

Comment: Working from the less error prone. What is happening THIS is the outstanding and what does next do? I get the rest

Comment: if you look at the HTML in that fiddle. you will find the classes being added to respective <td>. its easy to identify elements using class name and its more consistent... $(this) represent the current HTML element in .each(), so when .each() loops, it will go to first .outstanding div, which is presented with $(this) and its html is $(this).html because <td> has no value, you can not use .val() on <td>

Comment: .next() moves from current html element to next html element, in this case it moves from <td> to next <td> and within next <td> it tries to find (.paidAmount) within that <td> and puts the value in textbox

Answer (score 1):

`.Closest` will search for the ancestor elements, In your case the target `input` is the children of the next sibling of the selected element. So you have to use `.find()` or `.children()` to select that.

Try,

```
$('#pay_in_full').click(function(){
    $("[id^='charge_outstanding_']").each(function(){
        charge = parseInt($(this).text());
        $(this).next().find('input').val(charge);
    });
});
```

Additionally, You are selecting a `td element`, so you have to use `.text()` to get its text not `.val()`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F5NvW/3/)